# Routed port on BNT 8124 (Blade Networks/IBM switch)

Tags: networking, cisco, routing

How can I create a routed port on a BNT 8124?

I need to create a /30 routed link between the BNT 8124 and a Cisco 4948

I have a port configured with:

```
interface port 22
name "BNT_Routed_Link"
exit
```

But I can't add an IP to it.

The software version is 6.8.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to put interface ip and add that interface into vlan, after that assign port to that vlan.